# Interface Freezing at Beginning of Text Input

Tags: 22.04, freeze, interface, input

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4. A few weeks ago, there was an update that asked me to restart the computer when it completed. Since then I've been having a problem with text input.

Often, if I switch application or text input box within an application, or go without typing anything for a while, I find that when I press a key to start typing my computer freezes for a few seconds, after which it normally writes out the character I was trying to type *twice*, followed by those I typed before noticing the machine had frozen (e.g. writing "LLinux" instead of "Linux"). There are a couple of slight variations on what happens, but it's normally as I just described. As well as being a nuisance when I try to search or type an address in Firefox, it also causes a problem when I'm using the terminal a lot for work -- I'll press the `UP` arrow key to get my previous command and it'll register twice. Then I'll press enter from muscle-memory and do the wrong thing.

If I'm typing continuously without pause or switching where I'm typing (like now for example), I don't have any problems by and large. I also don't seem to encounter the problem while gaming, as far as I've noticed.

I put off asking for help for a while as I hoped that an update might fix what had been broken by an update, but this has not occurred some weeks after the fact.

Does anyone have any suggestions as how to diagnose and fix this problem? Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Switching from X11 to Wayland has helped. I don't get the freezing or letter duplication on text input anymore. Instead, very very occasionally, the interface freezes for a couple of seconds after I start moving the mouse for the first time in a while or sometimes when I open the workspace overview from some apps.